# Continuously send sendor data via DatagramSocket

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, networking, android-sensors

I'm trying to implement an application, which is going to continuously send data from the mobile device Accelerometer to the PC via UDP protocol.

So, at this moment I realised that to receive data from the device Accelerometer I need to create a new `SensorEventListener` and override `onSensorChanged()` method and and to handle sensor data from the `event` variable, like this:

```
private class AccelerationListener implements SensorEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //handle event data here
    }
}
```

That's pretty clear for me.

To send a message via DatagramSocket I've created a new Runnable:

```
private class UDPSend implements Runnable {

    private byte[] message;

    UDPSend(byte[] message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();

            InetAddress receiverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                    message, 
                    message.length, 
                    receiverAddress, 
                    SERVER_PORT
            );

            datagramSocket.send(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And then invoke this `Runnable` in the `onSensorChanged()` method like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        String message = event.timestamp + " " 
                 + event.values[0] + " " 
                 + event.values[1] + " " 
                 + event.values[2];
        new Thread(new UDPSend(message.getBytes())).start();
    }
```

It's working just fine and my udp server succesfully receives sensor data.

So, my question - regarding to the fact, that I've set `SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` as an update rate for my `SensorEventListener` it creates thousands of threads to handle this `SensorEvent` spam. I'm afraid that it could badly affect the performance of the application and wondering is there any other way to deal with threading, but continue to send data continuously?

Comment: Your hunch is correct. Creating a thread for every datagram to be sent is not a viable solution. You need to either use thread pools, or (better approach in my view) create a dedicated thread, which would subscribe to the sensor readings and send the data from the same notification callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The simplest way to do manage the large number of threads to get rid of  creating threads all together and send the sensor reads synchronously:

   ```
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       String message = event.timestamp + " " 
                + event.values[0] + " " 
                + event.values[1] + " " 
                + event.values[2];
       (new UDPSend(message.getBytes())).run();
   }
   ```
2. Use a ThreadPool, this way you will have only one thread:

   ```
   class Sender {

      final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

      public void send(byte[] bytes) {
          pool.submit(new UDPSend(bytes);   
      }
   }


   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
           String message = event.timestamp + " " 
                    + event.values[0] + " " 
                    + event.values[1] + " " 
                    + event.values[2];
           sender.send(message.getBytes());
   }
   ```